# Mechanics behind adding two arrays in D language

Tags: arrays, d

I am a bit curious mechanics behind code below:

```
int[3] a1 = [ 1 , 2 , 3 ];
int[3] a2 = [ 1 , 2 , 3 ];
int[3] result = a1[] + a2[];
foreach (i; result)
    writeln(i);
```

Result is 2,4,6 . In C++ we had to overload '+' operator for it to take two vectors to achive this or use std::transform. I checked a little the implementation doc of array([std_array.html](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_array.html)). I couldn't find out any overload for '+', I think D is somehow managing this by checking if the data integral type or something but I am just guessing.

Can somebody explain how this actually works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is part of the language itself:

http://dlang.org/arrays.html#array-operations

The implementation may do different things as long as it gives the result, which gives enough flexibility for automatic optimizations. Currently, looking at a disassembly, it compiles to a function call, similar to an operator overload, just done automatically.

Comment: It is really interesting, before marking the answer as accepted one more thing triggerred in my mind. I haven't tried but what if I use a user defined type instead of int as array value. How this is going to work? How compiler will understand what I meant by + for my own struct? Will it give an error ?

Comment: Trying it gives a good error message: `Error: invalid array operation 'a2[] += a1[]' because Foo doesn't support necessary arithmetic operations`. If you add an overload for plus: `Foo opOpAssign(string op)(Foo rhs) { return Foo(); }`, then it compiles. It still compiles to an automatically inserted function call: `arraySliceSliceAddass_S1b3Foo` (mangle to English: array slice add assign for a Struct named b.Foo - my file is called b.d for the example). This function is also auto generated, its implementation is a loop over all the members, calling the overloaded function.

Comment: Thanks a lot, sorry I didn`t had chance to compile myself. I also asked because I thought it might be useful for readers.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong about the implementation in D, but I think this would be pretty close.

Well arrays in D are made up by a length and a pointer. The mechanics behind such thing is really simple. You basically allocates memory for a default size and once the array has been filled with elements and another element is appended then you simply reallocates memory and adds the element.

Here is some quick code I did. It has only been tested to the minimum.

C Libraries:

```
import std.c.stdlib : malloc, realloc, free;
import std.c.string : memcpy;
```

Source:

```
/**
*   A dynamic array.
*   T would be the type of the array
*/
struct DynamicArray(T) {
    T* array; // A pointer to the elements of the array
    size_t nextindex; // The next index
    size_t size; // The size of the array

    /**
    *   Allocates a new dynamic array with an initialization size.
    */
    this(size_t size = 0) {
        array = cast(T*)malloc(size * T.sizeof); // Allocates memory of the array for the default array size
        nextindex = 0; // The next index is 0 (Arrays are always 0 indexed)
        this.size = size; // The size of the array
    }

    /**
    *   Appends an element to the array and reallocates memory if necessary.
    */
    void appendElement(T e) {
        if (nextindex == size) { // If the next index is the size of the array
            size++; // Add one to the size (Since we're appending one element)
            array = cast(T*)realloc(array, size * T.sizeof); // Reallocate memory to fit the element
        }
        array[nextindex++] = e; // Adds the element to the index
    }

    /**
    *   Appends another array to the array and reallocates memory if necessary.
    */
    void appendArray(DynamicArray!T a) {
        // This could be done using realloc too and memcpy
        foreach (i; 0 .. a.size) {
            appendElement(a.array[i]);
        }
    }

    /**
    *   Gets an element by index.
    */
    T getByIndex(size_t index) {
        return array[index];
    }

    /**
    *   Gets a string of the array elements.
    */
    string toString() {
        import std.string : format;
        import std.array : join;
        import std.conv : to;

        string[] elements;
        foreach (i; 0 .. size)
            elements ~= to!string(getByIndex(i));
        return format("[%s]", join(elements, ", "));
    }

    ~this() {
        free(array);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
auto array1 = DynamicArray!int(5); // Initialize it with 5
foreach (int i; 0 .. 10) // Loops from 0 to 10, although the actual size of the array is 5
    array1.appendElement(i); // Appends i to the array and expands it as necessary
writeln(array1.toString); // Prints out the array

auto array2 = DynamicArray!int(10); // Initialize it with 10
foreach (int i; 0 .. 10) // Loops from 0 to 10
    array2.appendElement(i); // Appends i to the array, but does no reallocations, because the size is already 10
writeln(array2.toString); // Prints out the array

array1.appendArray(array2); // Appends array2 to array1
writeln(array1.toString); // Prints out array1
```

Output:

[image: Output SS]

Of course something like this shouldn't be used and I'm almost positive the implementation of dynamic arrays in D is a bit more complicated and different, but this should give you a view of how it's done.

## Edit

Here is an example that equals what you posted.

```
auto a1 = DynamicArray!int(3); // int[3] a1
// = [
a1.appendElement(1); // 1,
a1.appendElement(2); // 2,
a1.appendElement(3); // 3
// ];

auto a2 = DynamicArray!int(3); // int[3] a2
// = [
a2.appendElement(1); // 1,
a2.appendElement(2); // 2,
a2.appendElement(3); // 3
// ];

auto result = DynamicArray!int(3); // int[3] result
// result =
result.appendArray(a1); // a1
// +
result.appendArray(a2); // a2;
```

## Edit

Just checked up in the DMD source and I was pretty close with the implementation. The array implementation has a reserve function which calls malloc/realloc and the insert function also calls the reserve function.

https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/dmd/blob/master/src/root/array.h#L76

And

https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/dmd/blob/master/src/root/array.h#L198

Comment: You misunderstood the question - you explained about array appending, while the question was about element-wise batch operations on arrays. See answer by Adam D. Ruppe

Comment: Oh my bad, I thought he meant the actual implementation about the operator and what it does.

Comment: This is good information though. One difference is in the built-in arrays, the reserved size is not stored with the slice - it is actually stored with the memory block from the GC, so when you append, it looks it up from there. This keeps the slice as small as possible, and a thread-local cache from the gc keeps the append operation quick for the majority of cases. You can read more here: http://dlang.org/d-array-article.html